# Formatting Min and Max of each record in Google Visualization Table

Tags: php, ajax, formatting, google-visualization

Is there an easy way I can format each record in my table to distinguish the highest and lowest for that record? I've seen the arrow formatter but that looks like I need to provide a value and then it adds it to every cell. Not quite what I need but maybe I can modify that somehow to make it work for my case. Here is a table I would like to apply it to.

[image: http://s27.postimg.org/d0kw6x8zn/COGS.png]

For example,
In the first record JTB would be red and Orange Park would be green because it is cost of goods (lower is better). I can provide code if needed but I mostly just need a push in the right direction. I am using ajax to request the table and then php to generate the tables and then encode to JSON and return back to the ajax and then generate the Google visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually add cell properties to highlight the low/high values.  Assuming you have CSS classes `'low'` and `'high'` for low and high values, you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var lowIndices = [], highIndices = [], lowVal = null, highVal = null;
    for (var j = 1; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
        if (lowVal == null || data.getValue(i, j) < lowVal) {
            // if we have a new lowVal, reset lowVal and lowIndices
            lowVal = data.getValue(i, j);
            lowIndices = [j];
        }
        else if (data.getValue(i, j) == lowVal) {
            // if we tied a lowVal, add the new index
            lowIndices.push(j);
        }

        if (highVal == null || data.getValue(i, j) > highVal) {
            // if we have a new highVal, reset highVal and highIndices
            highVal = data.getValue(i, j);
            highIndices = [j];
        }
        else if (data.getValue(i, j) == highVal) {
            // if we tied a highVal, add the new index
            highIndices.push(j);
        }
    }
    // add the high/low classes to the appropriate cells
    for (var k = 0; k < lowIndices.length; k++) {
        data.setProperty(i, lowIndices[k], 'className', 'low');
    }
    for (var l = 0; l < highIndices.length; l++) {
        data.setProperty(i, highIndices[l], 'className', 'high');
    }
}
```